# Create new records within an existing RDD

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I am attempting to create more records within a RDD:

Now, I have a `RDD[(String, List(String))]`, and contents are:

```
("str_1", List("sub_str_1", "sub_str_2"))  
("str_2", List("sub_str_3", "sub_str_4")) 
("str_3", List("sub_str_5", "sub_str_6"))
```

I want to convert it to `RDD[(String, String)]`by flatting `list[String]`.
After conversion, the content should be

```
("str_1", "sub_str_1")
("str_1", "sub_str_2")
("str_2", "sub_str_3")
("str_2", "sub_str_4")
("str_3", "sub_str_5")
("str_3", "sub_str_6")
```

It seems that all methods that can be applied to RDD are not able to increase number of records. What I can do is just transforming current ones into new RDD with the same number of records.

My question: is there a way to increase number of records in RDD?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `flatMap`.

```
rdd.flatMap { case (str, list) => list.map(elt => (str, elt)) }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a special transformation:

```
rdd.flatMapValues(identity)
```